# How to draw lines (like google map) in regular HTML, CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

How can we draw lines (like google map) in regular HTML,CSS for sample offline app?

Comment: HTML5 came with many features. Who knows, HTML6 may contain this graphics feature or not! 
 & also take a look on the tags, there is not only HTML & CSS.

 nyway, thnx for responding

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Raphaël (vector graphics) library for JavaScript can allow you to do this fairly easily:

http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/

Comment: thanks man. let me try with it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. You should use canvas api.

Methods:
MoveTo()
LineTo()