# Android: Raphaeljs not working in webview

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-webview

I am opening a simple html page in webview, with Raphaeljs included.
Its drawing a circle and working in browser. But, in webview its not showing up.

Is there anything blocking rapaheljs to work in webview?

What is the alternate solution for that!

Comment: As of 2013 this shouldn't be a problem anymore, I put the raphael.js in my assets/www directory and it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Raphaeljs uses javascript to render SVGs. According to [this bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1376), the WebView doesn't currently support rendering SVGs. So you won't be able to see anything that Raphaeljs creates in a WebView.

Comment: ok.
Can u suggest something for drawing line- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641743/how-to-draw-lines-like-google-map-in-regular-html-css

Comment: Sorry, I'm not aware of any WebView compatible drawing libraries.